# owncloud 8.1 user provisioning api - not authorized

Tags: owncloud

I'm getting underway with ownCloud 8.1 community edition (installed via RPM on Centos7).  I'm starting with a dev system to test out things.

I've tried accessing the API to get a list of groups via the URL:

```
http://admin:admin@testlocal/owncloud/ocs/v1.php/cloud/groups
```

And via javascript:

```
function doMake() {
$.ajax({
 type: 'POST',
 url: 'http://testlocal/owncloud/ocs/v1.php/cloud/groups',
 crossDomain: true,
 beforeSend: function(xhr) {
   xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent('admin' + ':' + 'admin'))))
 }
}).done( function(data, status, xhr) {
    document.write(status);
}).fail( function(xhr, status, error) {
    document.write(status + ":" + error);  
});
```

}

Both return an Unauthorized response.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I got it working.

I had to enable SSL on the owncloud website.  Makes perfect sense since I'm putting credentials across the wire.  Nowhere did I see any docs or any examples that referred to HTTPS, but it looks like it was needed.

Searching around, there was an excellent guide at:

http://www.evilbox.ro/linux/enable-ssl-for-owncloud-8-on-ubuntu/

...that worked right out of the box for me to configure owncloud with SSL.

So the following URL now works:

```
https://admin:admin@testlocal/owncloud/ocs/v1.php/cloud/groups
```

I hope this helps someone.

Corey.